# How do I fix my code :error: Uncaught ReferenceError: account is not defined?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning elegant JS

I'm coding the and I can't the piece of code to work.

It's a simple piece of Javascript code.  I honestly thought I had done right but I keep getting this error and I am utterly confused as to what I have done wrong.

```js
let myAccount = {

  name: `John Smith`,
  expenses: 0,
  income: 0
}

let addExpense = function(account, amount) {

  account.expenses = account.expenses + amount

}

let addIncome = function(account, income) {

  account.income = account.income + income

}

let resetAccount = function() {

  account.expenses = 0
  account.income = 0
}


let getAccountSummary = function(account) {

  let balance = account.income - account.expenses

  return `Account for ${myAccount.name} has £${balance}. ${myAccount.income}  in income £${myAccount.expenses}`
}

addIncome(myAccount, 2000)
addExpense(myAccount, 2.50)
addExpense(myAccount, 160)

console.log(getAccountSummary(myAccount))
resetAccount(myAccount)
console.log(getAccountSummary(myAccount))
```

I keep getting `Uncaught Reference error.`

I've been looking at this for over a week. Totally lost

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
let resetAccount = function() {

  account.expenses = 0
  account.income = 0
}
```

to

```
let resetAccount = function(account) {

  account.expenses = 0
  account.income = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 let resetAccount = function(){
    
      account.expenses = 0
      account.income = 0
    }
```

for sure resetAccount will cause *Uncaught ReferenceError: account is not defined*, you probably want to add account parameter to resetAccount function.

**updated**

let resetAccount = function(account){

```
  account.expenses = 0
  account.income = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'resetAccount' function should have a parameter.

```
let resetAccount = function(account) {
  account.expenses = 0
  account.income = 0
}
```